# Retracted edit in Docs-beta is credited to the wrong account

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, suggested-edits, documentation-review

While browsing my bookmarks, I found out that edits to Documentation, that were retracted during private beta, are credited to the wrong SO account.

My docs-beta userid is 1663 while my SO userid is 5022249.

However, [this retracted edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/4660) of mine in docs-beta is credited to a SO user with userid, 1663, which was my docs-beta userid.

Not a major [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but it does seem a little weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We save the state of a proposed change at the moment of deletion as a JSON object saved in a database VARCHAR field. It looks like we use that data to reconstruct the deleted proposed change. So that means that *any* proposed change that was retracted before the end of the private beta will have the wrong creation user information in the review queue display.

It seems to me the *best* solution would be to rewrite the DataAtDeletion field in the database. I'm checking with the developers to see how easy (or not) this is to do. If we don't decide to fix the data, I'd suggest not showing the user for proposed changes retracted before the end of the private beta. In either case, the problem affects ~1800 retracted proposed changes.

Comment: I just did the rewrite, so all changes retracted before the data import should be assigned to their rightful owners.